# How to count consecutive entries in dplyr

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in R

```
  Date           Hour_Bucket         QC Type
  2017-01-01        0-1                6 QC 
  2017-01-01        1-2                6 QC
  2017-01-01        2-3                Less than 6 QC
  2017-01-01        3-4                Less than 6 QC
  2017-01-01        4-5                Less than 6 QC
  2017-02-01        0-1                6 QC
  2017-02-01        1-2                Less than 6 QC
  2017-02-01        2-3                Less than 6 QC
```

In above dataframe everyday will have 24 hour buckets and I have 10 months data. 
Now, what I want to find is consucative entries of `6 QC` and name them lets say `Set 1` for the next set of consucative entries of `6 QC` it should be `SET 2` 
and lets say there are 2 consucative entries of `6 QC` then for the next 2 entries it should say `SUBSET 1`

My Desired dataframe would be

```
    Date           Hour_Bucket         QC Type               Set
  2017-01-01        0-1                6 QC                  SET 1
  2017-01-01        1-2                6 QC                  SET 1
  2017-01-01        2-3                Less than 6 QC        SUBSET 1
  2017-01-01        3-4                Less than 6 QC        SUBSET 1
  2017-01-01        4-5                Less than 6 QC        NA
  2017-02-01        0-1                6 QC                  SET 2
  2017-02-01        1-2                Less than 6 QC        SUBSET 2
  2017-02-01        2-3                Less than 6 QC        NA
```

How can I do it in R?

Comment: Why are there `NA` values? Should the first be `SUBSET 1` and the second `SUBSET 2`?

Comment: @tyluRp I want to flag values next to the length of consucative values.if lets say there are 2 consucative `6 QC` then this should be labeled as `SET 1` and then next 2 should be labeled as `SUBSET 1` and so on

Comment: Ah, thanks. I think I get it now

Comment: Please provide your data in an easily reproducible form

Comment: you could use `rle()` on the `QC Type` column to get started